# Adding dependencies to a custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, plugins, gradle

I'm creating a gradle plugin that uses gson, but when I use the plugin at my client it throws this  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`
I expect I am linking my dependencies in the plugin in a wrong way, but i'm not quite sure so any help would be great.

The build.gradle in the plugin

```
group 'nl.daanluttik.gradle'
version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven' // the plugin to distribute to maven

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '1.7.2'
    compile gradleApi()/*The gradle plugin api*/
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

//To distribute to maven
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

A segment of the buildgradle in the client project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'nl.daanluttik.gradle', name: 'peach', version: '0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really the first error? I most often see `NoClassDefFoundError` (in contrast to `ClassNotFoundException`) if some static initializer threw some exception and because of that the class could not be loaded and is not available later on.

Comment: @BjörnKautler You are completely right. I will change it

Comment: Great, I made the commen an answer so you can act on it accordingly :-)

Comment: can you take a look in the pom.xml published with your plugin to your mavenLocal? does it contain the gson dependency?

Comment: did you try adding mavenCentral() to the buildscript section of your client project?

Comment: @RaGe if I add mavenCentral() to the buildscript I already get 'NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson' during gradle's sync task.

Comment: @RaGe I did some searching and I found that it doesn't contain a pom.xml  It does have an ivy-01.xml file that shows the dependency but I don't know if that counts.

Comment: you're using the maven plugin but you're producing an ivy repo descriptor? How?!

Comment: @RaGe I dont know. Everything is in the given build.gradle

Comment: @DaanLuttik Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @neu242 I think just did a workaround. I finished this project over 2 years ago and no longer have access to the repository, so I can't check.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really the first error? I most often see `NoClassDefFoundError` (in contrast to `ClassNotFoundException`) if some static initializer threw some exception and because of that the class could not be loaded and is not available later on.

Comment: If I run the plugin with --info and --debug I still don't see any error preceding 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' so I still have no idea where the problem comes from or how to solve it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood you. From the comment I thought that was your problem.

Comment: Thats ok, I meant that I'd change the problem description. The source of the problem is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the pom file with your dependencies.  If it's just java then you can easily use the `maven-publish` which will generate the pom for you correctly.

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'nl.daanluttik.gradle'
            artifactId 'peach'
            version '0.1'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can publish to the repositories (default local only) with `gradle publish`

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html