# Gradle throws ClassNotFoundException using a plugin with dependencies

Tags: gradle, apache-commons, gradle-plugin, apache-commons-config

I am experiencing `ClassNotFoundException`s when using a Gradle plugin with compile dependencies in a project in the same root folder.

The directory structure is rather simple, with a plugin and the project that will use it:

- root

  - `buildSrc`
  - `demo-project`

The `build.gradle` in `buildSrc` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.0'
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2'
}
```

And the plugin itself builds correctly.

When applying the plugin to my `demo-project`, the `afterEvaluate` part fails because it can't find the `commons-configuration2` dependencies (so the plugin executes, than fails at the incriminated line):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':demo-project'.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
```

Just to complete my question, here's the `build.gradle` in my `demo-project`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.sample.myplugin'

thisIsMyPluginConfiguration {
    something = 'here'
}
```

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround that I can use?

Might be related to [Adding dependencies to a custom gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955443/adding-dependencies-to-a-custom-gradle-plugin).

**EDIT**: Trying to specify a different dependency makes it work. It looks like it's an issue of how the culprit `PropertiesConfiguration` class is loaded. The full stacktrace is:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':demo-java'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:510)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.fetchBeanClass(BeanHelper.java:549)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBeanCreationContext(BeanHelper.java:616)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:456)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:479)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:492)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.createResultInstance(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:447)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.createResult(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:417)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:285)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.ConfigurationBuilder$getConfiguration.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.novoda.buildproperties.BuildProperties.<init>(BuildProperties.groovy:23)
        at com.novoda.buildproperties.BuildPropertiesPlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(BuildPropertiesPlugin.groovy:17)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:828)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:894)
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:877)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.loadClass(BeanHelper.java:507)
        at org.apache.commons.configuration2.beanutils.BeanHelper.fetchBeanClass(BeanHelper.java:545)
        ... 62 more
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

A search of the web suggested that Gradle uses custom class loaders to control the process. Here is some code used that enabled the PropertiesConfiguration to be discovered

```
ClassLoader gradleClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(PropertiesConfiguration.class.getClassLoader())

methodThatUsesPropertiesConfiguration()

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(gradleClassLoader)
```

Not being intimately familiar with the class loader mechanism of Gradle, this may have ramifications that others may share. However, the method called during this temporary switch does not interact with other Gradle functionality and so deemed it relatively safe.

Comment: Finally came across this after hours of digging around. Works for a devkit-based plugin as well. Thank you!